# How do I prevent an entire list from re-rendering when state of one component changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a list component that fetches data and maps the results over card-like child components to create a list of "cards". Below is a example:

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeTab: 1
    };
  }

  setActiveTab = (activeTab) => {
    this.setState({ activeTab });
  }

  render() {
    const activeTab = this.state.activeTab;

    return (
      <div className="card">
        <ul className="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
          <li 
            className="nav-item" 
            key={ 1 }
            onClick={ () => this.setActiveTab(1) }
          >
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Overview</a>
          </li>
          <li 
            className="nav-item" 
            key={ 2 }
            onClick={ () => this.setActiveTab(2) }
          >
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Data</a>
          </li>
          <li 
            className="nav-item" 
            key={ 3 }
            onClick={ () => this.setActiveTab(3) }
          >
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Edit</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h3 className="card-title">{ this.props.title }</h3>
        { activeTab === 1 && 
          <h5 className="card-text">
            { this.props.body }
          </h5>    
        }
        { activeTab === 2 && 
          <div className="card-data">
            <a>Yes: { this.props.yes }</a>
            <a>No: { this.props.no }</a>
          </div>
        }
        { activeTab === 3 &&
          <div>
            <a 
              href="/cards"
              onClick={ this.props.onDelete }
              className="delete-card"
            >
              Delete
            </a>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Card;


class CardList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCards();
  }

  renderCards() {
    return this.props.cards.reverse().map(({ _id, title, body, yes, no }) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={_id}
          title={title}
          body={body}
          yes={yes}
          no={no}
          onDelete={() => this.props.deleteSurvey(_id)}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">{this.renderCards()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Each card has tabs, clicking a tab determine which text is shown in each particular card. The tab/toggle is working, but my issue is that the entire list is re-rendering when the tab is clicked. So if you are at the bottom of the list, the re-render brings you back to the top of the list.

I've tried implementing componentShouldUpdate, but with no success thus far. I would like for the card to toggle it's content and the list remain in place. Is using the shouldUpdate lifecycle method the correct route? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: I think problem is giving  href="#" . remove it and see if it works.An internal state update of child will not trigger parent re-render unless child is updating some state in parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `<a>` **anchor** tag you have **href="#"**` which will always re-direct you to a new link. (# will re-direct to current page re-rendering everything).

> **Easiest Solution** is to **remove href="#"** which will remove your `cursor: pointer;` styling but you can re-add that back into your
>   `nav-item` classname.

Another simple solution is you can move the **onClick** into the **anchor** tag and adding **evt.preventDefault()** (Which prevents the event handler from doing the **default** action which is loading the page to the href) However this will make it so that you have to click the anchor tag so if you have padding between the `<li>` and `<a>` this might not be your best solution.

```
<li 
  className="nav-item"
  key={ 3 } 
>
  <a 
    className="nav-link" 
    href="#" 
    onClick={ (e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.setActiveTab(3); } }
  >
    Edit
  </a>
</li>
```

However Thai Duong Tran made a good point where you don't want to re-create the function every time.

> **Best solution** is to move your anonymous function into a class function. (This solution also removes the href="#" so you need to add `cursor: pointer;` into your css if you want that style)

```
 <li 
   className="nav-item" 
   data-tab={ 1 }
   onClick={this.onNavClick}
 >
   <a className="nav-link">Overview</a>
 </li>

 onNavClick = (evt) => {
   this.setState({activeTab: evt.target.dataset.tab});
 }
```

Also your delete action has the same issue where you added a href="/card" so you want to be careful with that.

If you want to have route actions to move to different pages/URL. You should look into adding `react-router`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the prbolem

```
 onClick={ () => this.setActiveTab(2) }
```

Essentially, `React` decides to re-render a component when it detects a `change` in component state or props, and it only does shallow comparison for object.

As you are using closures, these function is dynamically re-created every time the `Card` component render function is called. React detects a new object (in JS, function is treated as object) passed to the `li` element, then it redraws it.

To solve this problem you can do something like:

```
<li className="nav-item" data-tab={ 1 }
                            onClick={this.navLinkClickHandler}>
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Overview</a>
                        </li>
```

Then have `navLinkClickHandler` defined in your component:

```
navLinkClickHandler = (evt) => this.setState({activeTab: evt.target.dataset.tab})
```

More on React reconcilation can be found here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

And about using closure in render function:

https://reda-bx.gitbooks.io/react-bits/content/conventions/08.closures-in-render.html

Comment: Thats a great explanation and makes great sense. However, it doesn't seem to be quite working. When i created the navHandleClick , the data change wasn't occurring. When i added a console.log of evt.target.dataset the result was "DOMStringMap"

Comment: @Jameson did you miss `data-tab={ 1 }` in his code? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside CARD component (If you have not tried it already). Might work fine.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
   if(this.state.activeTab  === nextState.activeTab ){
      return false
   } else {
      return true
   }
}
```